# Does the vector <a,-a> have a name?

Tags: vectors

Is there a general term which describes the pair, a number "a" and it's negative counterpart "-a". Where is it defined? You can write these numbers as sets or vectors, so I am wondering if there is a general name for it.

My reason for asking is I am wondering if there is a pattern to the constants of partial fractions.
i.e $$\frac{A}{x+m}+\frac{B}{x-n}=\frac{1}{(x-n)(x+m)},\text{where n and m are elements of integers}$$
what would the rule be for the set (n,m) for, where A=-B,and $$ A=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5}....)$$

Comment: I don't think so. You could say they form points on the line $x+y=0$

Comment: My reason for asking is I am wondering if there is a pattern to the constants of partial fractions. i.e A/(x-n)+B(x+m)

Comment: @zaqifier The partial fractions case means showing $A=B$ for your specific case. Did you show $A=-B$ and are searching for a name? [I don't think this is a vector case, however.]

Comment: @coffeemath I don't quite know what area it would be, I was hoping it maybe had a name in the world of algebraic vectors

Comment: As a rule, when you want to describe certain things but don't know a name for them, just say they're _of the form_ you then show, e.g. "if $m+n\ne0$, $\frac{1}{(x-n)(x+m)}$ admits a partial fraction decomposition of the form $\frac{A}{x+m}+\frac{-A}{x-n}$".